# Get users' application list in Facebook

Tags: facebook, api

I want to develop a facebook app such that when the user install my app. I can

1. Get the user's application list
2. Find his friend who use the same apps as him(categorized by apps)
3. Track whether the user receives recommendation for the app
4. Track what information each app needs from users.

I have little experience in facebook app developing. I want to know is it technical possible to achieve the above four aims using facebook api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, the feature to retrieve the list of applications the User has authorized is not exposed to any of the present Facebook's APIs.

Comment: plus 1 for the answer. you cant

Comment: except you forgot to give +1 !